# How to remove and object property from all array object and and pass by api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]

> const dd = filterdusers.map((item) => {
> delete item.role;
> return item;
> });

I have an array of elements with structuring like this image. So I want to remove the role property from every array element.

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure the object with unwanted item and take the rest.

This approach does not mutate the original data.

```
const dd = filterdusers.map(({ role, ...rest }) => rest);
```

Comment: in my Nodejs application this property not removing. In javascript, it's working

Comment: maybe you need to update your environment ...

Comment: like what? can you give me any example?